# What is auth.tenantId in firebase phone authentication in react expo?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-recaptcha/) for implementing firebase phone authentication into my react expo app. When I click the 'send verification code' button, it redirects to the ReCaptcha and I can solve it. When I click the 'confirm' button of the ReCaptcha it shows an error:
`Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'auth.tenantId')`

I created a project in the firebase console of course and added everything to the firebaseConfig. What does this error mean, where could it have happended and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to hand in the `auth` variable to the `PhoneAuthProvider`:

```
const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
```

Comment: I am not using Phone authentication. then why its coming to me ?