# firebase signinwithemailandpassword tenanid error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

Firebase signinwithemailandpassword is giving tenantid error. I don't get it. Why this error. Any help, pls ?

edit:
i searched on google with no help, thats why i posted in here. any one with any hint even, so that i can move forward

edit 2 - code:

```
...
import { auth } from "../../firebaseConfig";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
...
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userCreds.email, userCreds.password).then((response) => {
}).catch((error) => {
const errorCode = error.code;
const errorMessage = error.message;
}).finally(() => {
});
```

Comment: Check it this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411223/what-is-auth-tenantid-in-firebase-phone-authentication-in-react-expo helps you!

Comment: @VaibhavGehani... thanks... m looking into it

Comment: @VaibhavGehani... thanx a lot bro... same case here also... i was calling the "firbaseConfig.js" [import { auth } from "../../firebaseConfig";] is was only having... // Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};... actually "auth" i have initialized "firebaseInit.js"... revised code is "import { auth } from "../../firebaseInit";"... and it works like a charm... thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Import auth from `firebaseInit` rather than importing it from `firebaseConfig`.

Change the auth import to below code

```
import { auth } from "../../firebaseInit"
```

Answer (score -1):

issue resolved...
instead of calling config file

import { auth } from "../../firebaseConfig";

i must have called init file

"import { auth } from "../../firebaseInit";"

i have initialzed auth in init file and not in config file... my bad